# String sort order (LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE)

Tags: postgresql

Apparently PostgreSQL allows different locales for each database since version 8.4
So I went to the docs to read about locales (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/locale.html).

String sort order is of my particular interest (I want strings sorted like 'A a b c D d' and not 'A B C ... Z a b c').

Question 1: Do I only need to set LC_COLLATE (String sort order) when I create a database?

I also read about LC_CTYPE (Character classification (What is a letter? Its upper-case equivalent?))

Question 2: Can someone explain what this means?

Answer (score 2):

The sort order you describe is the standard in most locales.
Just try for yourself:

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table('D d a A c b', ' ') ORDER BY 1;
```

When you initialize your db cluster with [initdb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/app-initdb.html) you can can pick a locale with `--locale=some_locale`. In my case it's `--locale=de_AT.UTF-8`. If you don't specify anything the locale is inherited from the environment - your current system locale will be used.

The template database of the cluster will be set to that locale. When you create a new database, it inherits the settings from the template. Normally you don't have to worry about *anything*, it all just works.

Read the chapter on [CREATE DATABASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-createdatabase.html) for more.
If you want to speed up text search with indexes, be sure to read about [operator classes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/indexes-opclass.html), as well.
 <sub>All links to version 8.4, as you specifically asked for that.</sub>

---

In **PostgreSQL 9.1** or later, there is [collation support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/collation.html) that allows more flexible use of collations:

> The collation feature allows specifying the sort order and character
>   classification behavior of data per-column, or even per-operation.
>   This alleviates the restriction that the LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE
>   settings of a database cannot be changed after its creation.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to other databases, PostgreSQL is a lot more stringent about case sensitivity. To avoid this when ordering you can use string functions to make it case sensitive:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY LOWER(last_name), LOWER(first_name);
```

If you have a lot of data it will be inefficient doing this across a whole table every time you want to display a list of records. An alternative is to use the [citext module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/citext.html), which provides a type that is internally case insensitive when doing comparisons.

Bonus:

You might come into this issue when searching too, in this there is a case insensitive pattern matching operator:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name ILIKE "%john%";
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for question 1 (One)

The LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE settings are determined when a database is created, and cannot be changed except by creating a new database.