# Postgres locale error

Tags: postgresql, unix, ubuntu, locale

I have a Postgres database hosted on Digital River, on Ubuntu, and [followed these instructions to install](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-12-04):

But something is wrong with the locale settings and I cannot work out how to fix it. When I run the psql command I get the following error:

```
postgres@assay:/home/deployer$ psql
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
psql (9.1.9)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thank you very much to Kamal Nasser on the Digital River forums for providing the correct answer (*the following commands below requires root privileges*):

```
$ locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8 
$ dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

I think this is the correct link to the original answer: the Digital Ocean site is not responding so I can't check it. 
 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/postgresql-and-rails-4

Comment: [Some explanation for this correct answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410742/set-order-by-to-ignore-punctuation-on-a-per-column-basis/17412110#17412110) Also, could you add a link to Kamal's answer?

Comment: This was what also work for me from 4-5 other similar, but obviously different answers

Answer (score 16):

After trying ardochhigh's answer:

```
$ sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8 
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

the problem persisted

After that I saw this answer that solved the problem for me:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/language-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04

Aparently LAGUAGE shell variable is not set:

```
$ sudo bash

$ export LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"
$ echo 'LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/default/locale
$ echo 'LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/default/locale

$ # next: logout and login
```

Comment: Just a note: if you are logged via ssh, the problem could be in your system terminal.
Adding these two lines to your `.bashrc` or `.profile` file will made the trick for me and my mate @forons:
`export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`
`export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: @Kuzeko totally! Note if you want to set this for all your users you add the missing env variables in `/etc/environment` like `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`. You might also need to set other variables depending on your error as `LANG`,`LANGUAGE`.